# What is the name of the knit stitch on these given pictures?

Tags: knitting, technique-identification

what is the name of the knit stitch in the pictures on this page:

https://www.pimkie.fr/p/pull-grosse-maille-408383E23A0B.html

[image]

Are there some patterns online using the same stitch?

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

That sweater is probably made on a knitting machine, but you can reproduce the look on knitting needles. It looks like either [fisherman's rib or brioche stitch](https://www.interweave.com/article/knitting/fishermans-rib-vs-brioche-stitch/), with added [tuck stitches](https://newstitchaday.com/how-to-knit-the-tuck-stitch/) every 3 or 4 rows. To make a tuck stitch, instead of knitting into the next live stitch, you knit into that stitch *and* the stitch below it.

Brioche and tuck stitches are a broad category including many stitch patterns. You can find knitting patterns with these stitches [on Ravelry with the search filter Attributes: Fabric Characteristics - brioche / tuck stitch](https://www.ravelry.com/patterns/search#pa=brioche-tuck).